# Span Tikz y y graph across two columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I want to add more datapoints to my X axis, however it seems like the graph is fixed. Is there a way to make it span across two columns? [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        scale only axis,
        scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
    }
    \begin{axis}[
      axis y line*=left,
      ymin=85, ymax=100,
      ymajorgrids = true,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
          anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
      symbolic x coords={3x3\\Filter, Dsmp\\ (1/2),Integer,Dsmp\\ + Int, Dsmp\\ + 3X3,Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=90,inner xsep=5pt},
        x tick label style={font=\small,align=center},
      ylabel=Accuracy(\%),
    ]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=x,brown]
      coordinates{
        (3x3\\Filter,98.98)
        (Dsmp\\ (1/2),97.62)
        (Integer,95.86)
        (Dsmp\\ + Int,91.52)
        (Dsmp\\ + 3X3,93.26)
        (Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int,90.18)
    }; \label{plot_one}
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[
      axis y line*=right,
      axis x line=none,
          legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
          anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
      symbolic x coords={3x3\\Filter, Dsmp\\ (1/2),Integer,Dsmp\\ + Int, Dsmp\\ + 3X3,Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int},
     xtick=data,
      nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},
      ymin=0, ymax=100,
      ylabel=Frames Per Second (FPS)
    ]
    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{Accuracy}
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue]
      coordinates{
        (3x3\\Filter,40)
        (Dsmp\\ (1/2),30)
        (Integer,20)
        (Dsmp\\ + Int,15)
        (Dsmp\\ + 3X3,10)
        (Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int,5)
    }; \addlegendentry{FPS}
    \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For future questions please always provide a full MWE starting with `\documentclass{...}` and loading all necessary packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little confusing what you actually want to achive and why you overlap to plots, but you can adjust the width of the plot with `width=20cm` and then you have to add the points in your `symbolic x coords={...}`.
Here I added two points AddPoint1 and AddPoint2.

In case of standalone class this problem does not occur because it will automatically adjust to the size.

The follwoing will also work in documentclass article:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
            scale only axis,
            scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
        }
        \begin{axis}[   
            axis y line*=left,
            ymin=85, ymax=100,
            ymajorgrids = true,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={3x3\\Filter, Dsmp\\ (1/2),Integer,Dsmp\\ + Int, Dsmp\\ + 3X3,Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int, AddPoint1, AddPoint2},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=90,inner xsep=5pt},
            x tick label style={rotate=90,font=\small,align=center},
            ylabel=Accuracy(\%),
            ]
            \addplot[smooth,mark=x,brown]
            coordinates{
                (3x3\\Filter,98.98)
                (Dsmp\\ (1/2),97.62)
                (Integer,95.86)
                (Dsmp\\ + Int,91.52)
                (Dsmp\\ + 3X3,93.26)
                (Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int,90.18)
                (AddPoint1,95)
                (AddPoint2,99)
            }; \label{plot_one}
        \end{axis}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            axis y line*=right,
            ylabel near ticks, 
            yticklabel pos=right,
            axis x line=none,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={3x3\\Filter, Dsmp\\ (1/2),Integer,Dsmp\\ + Int, Dsmp\\ + 3X3,Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int, AddPoint1, AddPoint2},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},
            ymin=0, ymax=100,
            ylabel=Frames Per Second (FPS)
            ]
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{Accuracy}
            \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue]
            coordinates{
                (3x3\\Filter,40)
                (Dsmp\\ (1/2),30)
                (Integer,20)
                (Dsmp\\ + Int,15)
                (Dsmp\\ + 3X3,10)
                (Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int,5)
                (AddPoint1,6)
                (AddPoint2,7)
            }; \addlegendentry{FPS}
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Forcing the width to certain value without rotating the x axis:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        scale only axis,
        scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
    }
    \begin{axis}[
        width=20cm,
        axis y line*=left,
        ymin=85, ymax=100,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        symbolic x coords={3x3\\Filter, Dsmp\\ (1/2),Integer,Dsmp\\ + Int, Dsmp\\ + 3X3,Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int, AddPoint1, AddPoint2},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=90,inner xsep=5pt},
        x tick label style={font=\small,align=center},
        ylabel=Accuracy(\%),
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=x,brown]
        coordinates{
            (3x3\\Filter,98.98)
            (Dsmp\\ (1/2),97.62)
            (Integer,95.86)
            (Dsmp\\ + Int,91.52)
            (Dsmp\\ + 3X3,93.26)
            (Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int,90.18)
            (AddPoint1,95)
            (AddPoint2,99)
        }; \label{plot_one}
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[
        width=20cm,
        axis y line*=right,
       ylabel near ticks, 
       yticklabel pos=right,
        axis x line=none,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        symbolic x coords={3x3\\Filter, Dsmp\\ (1/2),Integer,Dsmp\\ + Int, Dsmp\\ + 3X3,Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int, AddPoint1, AddPoint2},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        ylabel=Frames Per Second (FPS)
        ]
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{Accuracy}
        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue]
        coordinates{
            (3x3\\Filter,40)
            (Dsmp\\ (1/2),30)
            (Integer,20)
            (Dsmp\\ + Int,15)
            (Dsmp\\ + 3X3,10)
            (Dsmp\\ + 3X3\\ + Int,5)
            (AddPoint1,6)
            (AddPoint2,7)
        }; \addlegendentry{FPS}
    \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh i just wanted to add more points without it being scrunched up, i added 2 more points earlier and the x axis labels were touching each other.

Comment: What is getting scrunched up?

Comment: Its just because im resizing it to a single column. However i could angle it like you have done and there wouldnt be the need to expand it into two columns.

Comment: The Y axis's, are a little messed up

Comment: This is what your code produces. I did not change anything in the y axis. You can change it with `ylabel near ticks,` and `yticklabel pos=right,`.

Comment: Thanks!, ill mark it as a confirmed answer since you answered the original question.